# change css class with if-statement

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know if its possible to change the css class of a custom registration form field if the field is invalid so that i can make the borders/outlines of the field red via css.

Form validation:

```php
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields($username, $email, $validation_errors)
{
    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name']) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
        $validation_errors->add('billing_first_name_error', __('Error massage', 'woocommerce'));
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3);
}
```

Comment: use jquery or js - https://wp-qa.com/remove-required-validation-once-woocommerce-checkout-field-is-hidden

Comment: Most apps, and surely WooCommerce dynamically adds a class to invalid themes - look for that class with the Inspector and adjust your css accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately, I can't get any further with the post. The class is not automatically added.